nuxt 3 + yandex maps [map has not been initialized]
Я пытаюсь реализовать функционал, который будет находить улицу на карте при её вводе в поле и ставить метку. Это уже сделано.
Однако, когда я кликаю по карте, чтобы поставить метку, и пытаюсь вывести адрес улицы в поле ввода, возникает проблема. Карта не инициализируется, и при попытке клика по ней появляется ошибка: «Map instance or map element not found». Я сделал всё согласно документации, но всё равно сталкиваюсь с этой проблемой.
Буду благодарен за помощь в решении этой задачи!
<template>
  <div class="modal modal--place">
    <div class="modal__wrapper">
      <div class="modal__left">
        <div class="modal__header modal__header--big">Укажите ваш адрес</div>
        <div class="modal__appeal">
          Привезем товары в день заказа. Домой или в офис.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal__right">
        <button class="modal__close" @click="$emit('close-modal')">
          <svg class="modal__close-btn--image">
            <use xlink:href="/svg/symbols.svg#icon-close"></use>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form class="form-address">
      <input
        v-model="search"
        autocomplete="off"
        list="search"
        class="form-address__input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Укажите адрес доставки"
      />
      <datalist id="search">
        <option
          v-for="(item, index) in searchResponse ?? []"
          :key="item.geometry?.coordinates.join(',') ?? index"
          :value="item.geometry?.coordinates"
        >
          {{ item.properties.name }} ({{ item.properties.description }})
        </option>
      </datalist>
      <input
        class="form-address__submit"
        type="submit"
        value="Применить адрес"
      />
    </form>
    <div class="modal__map">
      <yandex-map
        v-model="map"
        height="500px"
        :settings="{
          location: {
            center: [42.0425, 44.21],
            zoom: 16,
          },
          showScaleInCopyrights: true,
        }"
        width="100%"
        @click="onClick"
      >
        <yandex-map-default-scheme-layer />
        <yandex-map-default-features-layer />
        <yandex-map-default-marker
          v-if="selectedSearch"
          :settings="{ coordinates: selectedSearch, title: 'Результат поиска' }"
        />
      </yandex-map>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {
  getBoundsFromCoords,
  getLocationFromBounds,
  YandexMap,
  YandexMapDefaultFeaturesLayer,
  YandexMapDefaultMarker,
  YandexMapDefaultSchemeLayer,
} from "vue-yandex-maps";
import { ref, shallowRef, watch, onMounted } from "vue";
import type { SearchResponse } from "@yandex/ymaps3-types/imperative/search";
import type { SuggestResponse } from "@yandex/ymaps3-types/imperative/suggest";
import type { LngLat, YMap } from "@yandex/ymaps3-types";

const map = shallowRef<null | YMap>(null);

const selectedSearch = shallowRef<LngLat | null>(null);
const selectedSuggest = shallowRef<LngLat | null>(null);

const search = shallowRef("");
const searchResponse = shallowRef<null | SearchResponse>(null);
const suggestResponse = shallowRef<null | SuggestResponse>(null);
const suggest = ref("");

function sleep(ms: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

watch(search, async (val) => {
  if (!val) return;

  if (val.split(/[,.]/).length === 4) {
    selectedSearch.value = val.split(",").map((x) => parseFloat(x)) as LngLat;
    return;
  }

  await sleep(300);
  if (val !== search.value) return;

  searchResponse.value = await ymaps3.search({
    text: val,
    bounds: map.value?.bounds,
  });
});

watch(suggest, async (val) => {
  if (!val) return;

  const existing = suggestResponse.value?.find((x) => x.subtitle?.text === val);
  if (existing) {
    const afterSuggestSearch = await ymaps3.search({
      text: val,
      type: ["toponyms"],
      bounds: map.value?.bounds,
    });
    if (afterSuggestSearch[0].geometry?.coordinates) {
      selectedSuggest.value = afterSuggestSearch[0].geometry.coordinates;
      return;
    }
  }

  await sleep(300);
  if (val !== suggest.value) return;
  suggestResponse.value = await ymaps3.suggest({
    text: val,
    bounds: map.value?.bounds,
    types: ["biz"],
  });
});

watch([selectedSuggest, selectedSearch], async () => {
  console.log("selectedSuggest:", selectedSuggest.value);
  console.log("selectedSearch:", selectedSearch.value);
  if (selectedSuggest.value && !selectedSearch.value) {
    map.value?.setLocation({
      center: selectedSuggest.value,
      zoom: 15,
      duration: 300,
    });
  } else if (!selectedSuggest.value && selectedSearch.value) {
    map.value?.setLocation({
      center: selectedSearch.value,
      zoom: 15,
      duration: 300,
    });
  } else if (selectedSuggest.value && selectedSearch.value) {
    map.value?.setLocation({
      ...(await getLocationFromBounds({
        bounds: getBoundsFromCoords([
          selectedSearch.value,
          selectedSuggest.value,
        ]),
        map: map.value!,
        comfortZoomLevel: true,
      })),
      duration: 300,
    });
  }
});

const coords = shallowRef([42.0425, 44.21]);

import { nextTick } from "vue";
onMounted(async () => {
  await nextTick();
  if (!map.value) {
    console.error("Map has not been initialized.");
  } else {
    console.log("Map initialized:", map.value);
  }
});

function onClick(event: PointerEvent) {
  try {
    console.log("Click event:", event); // Логируем объект события
    const mapInstance = map.value;
    if (mapInstance && mapInstance.$el) {
      // Вычисляем координаты клика относительно элемента карты
      const rect = mapInstance.$el.getBoundingClientRect();
      const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
      const y = event.clientY - rect.top;

      // Преобразуем координаты клика в географические координаты
      const newCoords = mapInstance.getCoordsAtPixel([x, y]);
      console.log("New coordinates from click:", newCoords); // Логируем координаты
      if (newCoords) {
        coords.value = newCoords;
        selectedSearch.value = newCoords;
        console.log("Updated selectedSearch:", selectedSearch.value); // Логируем обновление selectedSearch
        // Установка новой позиции карты на метку
        mapInstance.setLocation({
          center: newCoords,
          zoom: 15,
          duration: 300,
        });
      } else {
        console.error("Failed to get coordinates from click.");
      }
    } else {
      console.error("Map instance or map element not found.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in onClick handler:", error); // Логируем ошибку
  }
}
</script>


https://vue-yandex-maps.github.io/guide/#nuxt-module модуль заплагинил?
